# RegExp-filtering particular file path using directory and file extension blacklisting

Tags: regex, filtering, filepath, regex-lookarounds

I have the example path:

```
/var/ftp/video/Portuguese/Portuguese-Daniel/Animação Inicial/CLIPS/Torsten.Sturmwellen.Veith/Wellen_00653.tif
```

I need to blacklist */var/ftp/video/English* directory as well as some file extensions (such as doc/docx/ppt/pptx/tif/tiff/pdf/jpg/DS_Store)

The RegExp I use is:

```
^(?!\/var\/ftp\/video\/English)(.*\.(?!doc.*$|ppt.*$|jpg.*$|tif.*$|pdf.*$|DS_Store.*$)[^.]+)
```

But it doesn't work, because it matches this example path (but without the extension).
To do my tests I use http://regex101.com/ site.

What is a problem in my RegExp?

Comment: Why you added `[^.]+` at the last(ie, after to `$`)?

Comment: To catch the extension if file path is valid (no blacklist have been applied)

Comment: Are there possible GET variables `.ext?var1=value1&var2=value2...` or path `.ext/dir1/dir2` after this extension? and what language you will use?

Comment: Why do you add `.*` after each extension? If they are extensions (and there are no GET vars), isn't it supposed to be the end of the path? Aslo, why is there `.*+` after `doc`?

Comment: Because it may be not only doc, by also docx. Sorry, changed .*+ to .* but it not resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
^(?!\/var\/ftp\/video\/English)(.*\.(?!(doc.?|ppt.?|jpg|tif.?|pdf|DS_Store)$)([^.]+$))
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
(.*\.(?!doc.*$|ppt.*$|jpg.*$|tif.*$|pdf.*$|DS_Store.*$)[^.]+)
```

explicitly excludes the extension. This is why your expression does not work.

The expression

```
(.*\.(?!doc.*$|ppt.*$|jpg.*$|tif.*$|pdf.*$|DS_Store.*$).*)
```

includes the extension.

Tested with this perl code:

```
$a="/var/ftp/video/Portuguese/Portuguese-Daniel/Animação Inicial/CLIPS/Torsten.Sturmwellen.Veith/Wellen_00653.tif";

if ($a=~/^(?!\/var\/ftp\/video\/English)(.*\.(?!doc.*$|ppt.*$|jpg.*$|tif.*$|pdf.*$|DS_Store.*$).*+)/) {
print "$1\n";}
```

result:

```
/var/ftp/video/Portuguese/Portuguese-Daniel/Animação Inicial/CLIPS/Torsten.Sturmwellen.Veith/Wellen_00653.tif
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to blacklist the TIFFs. It should return no match.

Comment: ok. then you need to use look behind (?<!), not lookahead (?!): /^(?!\/var\/ftp\/video\/English)(.*(?<!\.doc|\.ppt|\.jpg|\.tif|\.pdf)$)/ Problem in my implementation this requires same length in every word of the look behind expression.